# How to easily share a sample dataframe using df.to_dict()

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

Despite the clear guidance on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), many just seem to ignore to include a reproducible data sample in their question. So what is a practical and easy way to reproduce a data sample when a simple `pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(5, 5)))` is not enough? How can you, for example, use [df.to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and include the output in a question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### The answer:

In many situations, using an approach with `df.to_dict()` will do the job perfectly! Here are two cases that come to mind:

**Case 1:** *You've got a dataframe built or loaded in Python from a local source*

**Case 2:** *You've got a table in another application (like Excel)*

---

#### The details:

**Case 1:** *You've got a dataframe built or loaded from a local source*

Given that you've got a pandas dataframe named `df`, just

1. run `df.to_dict()` in you console or editor, and
2. copy the output that is formatted as a dictionary, and
3. paste the content into `pd.DataFrame(<output>)` and include that chunk in your now reproducible code snippet.

---

**Case 2:** *You've got a table in another application (like Excel)*

Depending on the source and separator like `(',', ';' '\\s+')` where the latter means any spaces, you can simply:

1. `Ctrl+C` the contents
2. run `df=pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')` in your console or editor, and
3. run `df.to_dict()`, and
4. include the output in `df=pd.DataFrame(<output>)`

In this case, the start of your question would look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({0: {0: 0.25474768796402636, 1: 0.5792136563952824, 2: 0.5950396800676201},
                   1: {0: 0.9071073567355232, 1: 0.1657288354283053, 2: 0.4962367707789421},
                   2: {0: 0.7440601352930207, 1: 0.7755487356392468, 2: 0.5230707257648775}})
```

Of course, this gets a little clumsy with larger dataframes. But very often, all anyone who seeks to answer your question need is a little sample of your real world data to take the structure of your data into consideration.

#### And there are two ways you can handle larger dataframes:

1. run `df.head(20).to_dict()` to only include the first `20 rows`, and
2. change the format of your dict using, for example, `df.to_dict('split')` (there are [other options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) besides `'split'`) to reshape your output to a dict that requires fewer lines.

Here's an example using the [iris](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html) dataset, among other places available from plotly express.

If you just run:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = px.data.iris()
df.to_dict()
```

This will produce an output of nearly 1000 lines, and won't be very practical as a reproducible sample. But if you include `.head(25)`, you'll get:

```
{'sepal_length': {0: 5.1, 1: 4.9, 2: 4.7, 3: 4.6, 4: 5.0, 5: 5.4, 6: 4.6, 7: 5.0, 8: 4.4, 9: 4.9},
 'sepal_width': {0: 3.5, 1: 3.0, 2: 3.2, 3: 3.1, 4: 3.6, 5: 3.9, 6: 3.4, 7: 3.4, 8: 2.9, 9: 3.1},
 'petal_length': {0: 1.4, 1: 1.4, 2: 1.3, 3: 1.5, 4: 1.4, 5: 1.7, 6: 1.4, 7: 1.5, 8: 1.4, 9: 1.5},
 'petal_width': {0: 0.2, 1: 0.2, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.2, 4: 0.2, 5: 0.4, 6: 0.3, 7: 0.2, 8: 0.2, 9: 0.1},
 'species': {0: 'setosa', 1: 'setosa', 2: 'setosa', 3: 'setosa', 4: 'setosa', 5: 'setosa', 6: 'setosa', 7: 'setosa', 8: 'setosa', 9: 'setosa'},
 'species_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}}
```

And now we're getting somewhere. But depending on the structure and content of the data, this may not cover the complexity of the contents in a satisfactory manner. But you can include ***more data*** on ***fewer lines*** by including `to_dict('split')` like this:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris().head(10)
df.to_dict('split')
```

Now your output will look like:

```
{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 'columns': ['sepal_length',
  'sepal_width',
  'petal_length',
  'petal_width',
  'species',
  'species_id'],
 'data': [[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
  [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
  [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
  [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
  [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
  [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4, 'setosa', 1],
  [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3, 'setosa', 1],
  [5.0, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
  [4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
  [4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1, 'setosa', 1]]}
```

And now you can easily increase the number in `.head(10)` without cluttering your question too much. But there's one minor drawback. Now you can no longer use the input directly in `pd.DataFrame`. But if you include a few specifications with regards to `index, column, and data` you'll be just fine. So for this particluar dataset, my preferred approach would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

sample = {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
             'columns': ['sepal_length',
              'sepal_width',
              'petal_length',
              'petal_width',
              'species',
              'species_id'],
             'data': [[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
              [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
              [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
              [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
              [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
              [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4, 'setosa', 1],
              [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3, 'setosa', 1],
              [5.0, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
              [4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
              [4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1, 'setosa', 1],
              [5.4, 3.7, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
              [4.8, 3.4, 1.6, 0.2, 'setosa', 1],
              [4.8, 3.0, 1.4, 0.1, 'setosa', 1],
              [4.3, 3.0, 1.1, 0.1, 'setosa', 1],
              [5.8, 4.0, 1.2, 0.2, 'setosa', 1]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(index=sample['index'], columns=sample['columns'], data=sample['data'])
df
```

Now you'll have this dataframe to work with:

```
    sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species  species_id
0            5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa           1
1            4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa           1
2            4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa           1
3            4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa           1
4            5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa           1
5            5.4          3.9           1.7          0.4  setosa           1
6            4.6          3.4           1.4          0.3  setosa           1
7            5.0          3.4           1.5          0.2  setosa           1
8            4.4          2.9           1.4          0.2  setosa           1
9            4.9          3.1           1.5          0.1  setosa           1
10           5.4          3.7           1.5          0.2  setosa           1
11           4.8          3.4           1.6          0.2  setosa           1
12           4.8          3.0           1.4          0.1  setosa           1
13           4.3          3.0           1.1          0.1  setosa           1
14           5.8          4.0           1.2          0.2  setosa           1
```

Which will increase your chances of receiving useful answers significantly!

#### Edit:

`df_to_dict()` will not be able to read timestamps like `1: Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00')` without also including `from pandas import Timestamp`

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer! Could you please share some documents which your solution is based on? I couldn't find the relevant information. Much appreciate it!

Comment: @nilsinelabore The only documentaion I've used in this case is the pandas docs on [pandas.DataFrame.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) The rest of the answer is really just based on experience and reading a bunch of SO posts.