# plotly.js: hovertext for one bar in stacked bar chart

Tags: plotly, bar-chart

I have a stacked bar chart in plotly.js. I want only the top bar to show hover text and have no hover text for the bottom bar. I also do not want the text on the bottom to show, nor the word outside the hover box. Is there a way to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Please show is what you've tried with a reproducible code snippet and some sample data.

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-efficiently-build-and-share-a-sample-dataframe/63163254#63163254) for a quick and easy way to share a data sample.