# How to show only one state with Go.Scattergeo?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

[Reposted from community.plotly.com.](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-show-only-one-state-with-go-scattergeo/43471)

Basically, I’m making a Scatter plot filterable by state, and when I select, for example, Alabama, I want only the state of Alabama to show up, big and centered on the page - removing the rest of the United States. I was thinking of using either `locations` or `geojson` to accomplish this, but I’m not sure how I would use those in the way I wanted.

[Current view of all the states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb1O0.png)

[Current view of Alabama](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBjeS.png)

[Mock-up of what I want the state view to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/953Sy.png)

Edit:

[Reproducible code](https://pastebin.com/DTi6xBdq)

I've tried using `locations = [state_abbrv]`, but that just removes all the points and puts one point in the center of the map, [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlPCc.png)

Comment: @Coloradohuskey What have you tried? Please share code and sample data.

Comment: @vestland Added relevant information

Comment: @Coloradohuskey And data?

Comment: @vestland The data is NHTSA FARS data for 2018: https://www.nhtsa.gov/filebrowser/download/176791

Comment: @Coloradohuskey Why don't you include a sample in your question?

Comment: @Coloradohuskey If you're not sure *how*, then take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-efficiently-build-and-share-a-sample-dataframe/63163254#63163254). It's short and to the point on how to share your `df`.

Comment: @vestland Thanks, does what I put look good? You should be able to just paste it into a Python file and run it, assuming you have pandas, numpy, plotly, and screeninfo installed

Comment: Please have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: @Coloradohusky Why do you prefer shading your reproducible code snippet as a link and not as code in the question?

Comment: @vestland It was too big to fit in the character limit