# How to Convert/read the column which is in integer into string value in python pandas dataframe for plotting in plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv, plotly

[image]I have a csv file in which a column is having integer value, i want to **convert/read it as string** so that i can **plot that to graph using python plotly library**. I will update the code below here.
please someone help me to convert the column values into string.

**CSV File:**

build ID,Pass Percentage,original_pass_percent
420693,97,97
420543,97,97
421009,98,98
420638,100,100
420462,92,92
421382,100,100

Here i want to convert the build ID column into a string so that i can get that on the graph using python plotly

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from numpy import nan as NA
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from flask import Flask, render_template
import json
import plotly
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from flask import Flask, make_response
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


p = Path(r'c:\Users\shivarad\Documents')  # path to files
files = list(p.rglob('*graph22.csv'))  # get files



fig = go.Figure()
for f in files: 
    file_name = f.stem  
    df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype={'Pass Percentage': str, 'original_pass_percent':int})
    df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype={'Pass Percentage': int, 'build ID': str})
    df['build ID']=df['build ID'].astype(str)
    df = df.sort_values(by=['build ID'], axis = 0)  
    print(df.head())  
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['build ID'], y=df['Pass 
    Percentage'],mode='lines+markers',name=file_name))
fig.update_layout(title='Pass Percent VS Build ID of all the Test Suites',plot_bgcolor='rgb(230, 
230,230)',showlegend=True)
fig.show()
```

Thank you

Comment: `df["build ID"] = df["build ID"].astype(str)` should work?

Comment: Hi I have tried, but still on X axis  i am not able to get string values on x axis of the graph. I will update the screenshot in the above post

Comment: @darshangowdasr1995 Please replace `p = Path(r'c:\Users\shivarad\Documents')` with a [sample of your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-efficiently-build-and-share-a-sample-dataframe/63163254#63163254)