# Plotly: How to plot a line chart from two rows of data?

Tags: python, charts, plotly, line

I'm trying to do a benchmarking line chart of a login times of a website between two groups of user. My dataframe is as follows:

df:

```
Group     Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     June
A          12      62     44      34      15       25
B          55      43     42      29      42       33
```

How can I make a chart with two lines: A and B, with X axis being the months and y axis being the login times?
I appreciate any assistance on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! I'd be happy to help, but your question does not exactly meet many of the SO standards. Please take a look at [ask] a question, and tell us what you have tried. Also take a look at how to [share your data sample as a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguably easiest way to do this is transposing your dataframe using `df.T`, set the [pandas plotly backend to plotly](https://plotly.com/python/pandas-backend/) using `pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"`, and then just use `df.plot()`. If you've got your exact data in a pandas dataframe, you only need to use:

```
df.set_index('Group').T.plot()
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code with data sample:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': {0: 'A', 1: 'B'},
                     'Jan': {0: 12, 1: 55},
                     'Feb': {0: 62, 1: 43},
                     'Mar': {0: 44, 1: 42},
                     'Apr': {0: 34, 1: 29},
                     'May': {0: 15, 1: 42},
                     'June': {0: 25, 1: 33}}).set_index('Group')

df.T.plot()
```

Comment: This answer works really well. For those of you wondering, `df.T.plot()` returns a plotly `Figure` object, which can be operated on like any other `plotly.figure.Figure`. As an example, a title could be added as: `fig=df.T.plot(); fig.update_layout(title="Months")`