# Plotly-Dash: Dropdown options work but won't plot data

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am new to Dash. I am trying to plot a simple line plot and add a dropdown to change the data which comes from a dataframe (which is nested in a dictionary with other dataframes). Here is the dataframe:

```
df_vals['corn']

time    2m_temp_prod    2m_temp_area    total_precip_prod   total_precip_area
0   2020-09-19 00:00:00 299.346777  299.799234  0.000000    0.000000
1   2020-09-19 06:00:00 294.039512  294.443352  0.191070    0.286952
2   2020-09-19 12:00:00 292.959274  293.182931  0.155765    0.216606
3   2020-09-19 18:00:00 301.318046  301.767516  0.421768    0.485691
4   2020-09-20 00:00:00 300.623567  300.979650  0.363572    0.501164
... ... ... ... ... ...
56  2020-10-03 00:00:00 301.177141  301.052273  0.371209    0.408515
57  2020-10-03 06:00:00 295.874298  295.720135  0.281793    0.300564
58  2020-10-03 12:00:00 293.838787  293.686738  0.586887    0.549365
59  2020-10-03 18:00:00 302.384474  302.191334  0.492712    0.493798
60  2020-10-04 00:00:00 300.920766  300.817993  0.522374    0.531138
```

Here is the code where I attempt the plot.

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
cols=df_vals['corn'].columns[1:]
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='variables',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in cols],
                value='2m_temp_prod'
            )
        ]),
    dcc.Graph(id='plot')])
])

@app.callback(
    Output('plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('variables', 'value')])

def update_graph(variable_name):
    fig=px.line(x=df_vals['corn']['time'], y=df_vals['corn'][variable_name])
    return fig

app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

This makes a plot with the correct dropdown options, but there is no data being plotted. What am I doing wrong here? Trying to follow a tutorial on the Dash website, but appear to be tripping up something.

Comment: A proper datasample would be great. And what are your imports here?

Comment: Will include my imports in the future. I see why you want the data in that form. It’s just a really long output, so I figured it would be less preferable due to clutter. Will do that in the future as well. Thanks.

Comment: A little bit of clutter does not matter as long as it saves 20 minutes of wasted time trying to reproduce a problem =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely seem to be close to a solution here. Iactually think that you've only forgotten to `import plotly.express as px`. I took the time to make a proper data sample out of the data you provided in the question. And without any information of your imports I just had to go for my standard plotly and JupyteDash imports. Anyway, the snippet below will produce the following plot. And please take a look at how I've set up your dataframe. You can learn to make the same setup if you invest the few minutes it takes to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254).

#### Dash App - Plot 1

**Dropdown selection** = `'2m_temp_prod'`

[image]

#### Dash App - Plot 2

[image]

**Dropdown selection = `'total_precip_prod''`

#### Complete code

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, ClientsideFunction
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px

df=pd.DataFrame({'time':{0:'2020-09-1900:00:00',
                        1:'2020-09-1906:00:00',
                        2:'2020-09-1912:00:00',
                        3:'2020-09-1918:00:00',
                        4:'2020-09-2000:00:00',
                        5:'2020-10-0300:00:00',
                        6:'2020-10-0306:00:00',
                        7:'2020-10-0312:00:00',
                        8:'2020-10-0318:00:00',
                        60:'2020-10-0400:00:00'},
                        '2m_temp_prod':{0:299.346777,
                        1:294.039512,
                        2:292.95927400000005,
                        3:301.318046,
                        4:300.623567,
                        5:301.177141,
                        6:295.874298,
                        7:293.838787,
                        8:302.384474,
                        60:300.920766},
                        '2m_temp_area':{0:299.799234,
                        1:294.443352,
                        2:293.182931,
                        3:301.767516,
                        4:300.97965,
                        5:301.052273,
                        6:295.720135,
                        7:293.686738,
                        8:302.191334,
                        60:300.817993},
                        'total_precip_prod':{0:0.0,
                        1:0.19107000000000002,
                        2:0.15576500000000001,
                        3:0.42176800000000003,
                        4:0.363572,
                        5:0.371209,
                        6:0.28179299999999996,
                        7:0.5868869999999999,
                        8:0.492712,
                        60:0.522374},
                        'total_precip_area':{0:0.0,
                        1:0.286952,
                        2:0.216606,
                        3:0.485691,
                        4:0.501164,
                        5:0.408515,
                        6:0.300564,
                        7:0.549365,
                        8:0.49379799999999996,
                        60:0.531138}})

df_vals = {'corn':df}

app = JupyterDash(__name__)
cols=df_vals['corn'].columns[1:]

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='variables',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in cols],
                value='2m_temp_prod'
            )
        ]),
    dcc.Graph(id='plot')])
])

@app.callback(
    Output('plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('variables', 'value')])

def update_graph(variable_name):
    fig=px.line(x=df_vals['corn']['time'], y=df_vals['corn'][variable_name])
    fig.update_layout(template='plotly_dark')
    return fig

app.run_server(mode='inline', debug=True)
```

Comment: I’m away from my computer until tomorrow so I’m on mobile. I can’t see to find the difference between your code and mine. What did I miss? @vestland

Comment: @EliTurasky I'm not sure since I don't have your imports. But I *think* you were missing `import plotly.express as px`. But we can talk more when you get to try it out.

Comment: So I went on and re ran my code this morning and it worked. Weird stuff. Thanks for the help though. I am sure I'll be back with more Dash questions in the coming days ;)