# Plotly: How to generate side-by-side px.sunburst plots?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am using the following Python code to produce a sunburst plot:-

```
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('CellUsageStats.csv',dtype={'Population':int},keep_default_na=False)
print(df.head(50))
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['LibPrefix', 'MasterPrefixAbrHead', 'MasterPrefixAbrTail', 'Drive'], values='Population', color='Population', color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Inferno)
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='Pattern: %{currentPath}%{label}<br>Matches: %{value}<br>Percent of <b>%{parent}</b>: %{percentParent:0.2%f}<br>Percent of <b>%{entry}</b>: %{percentEntry:0.2%f}<br>Percent of <b>%{root}</b>: %{percentRoot:0.2%f}')
fig.show()
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='sunburst.html')
```

I have a second csv file that I use to produce another sunburst, using the same code above. How do I combine them to create side-by-side plots in the same html output? I found...

https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/

However, I really need px.sunburst attributes, and the examples in the above link use go.Sunburst, not px.sunburst. Is there a straightforward way to produce side-by-side plots from two different sets of data?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [subplots](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/)?

Comment: If you REALLY need to use Plotly Express plots, then I think you out of luck (see this [link](https://plotly.com/python/mixed-subplots/)). However, have you read the full documentation for go.Sunburst [here](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Sunburst.html) and are sure it doesn't have inputs for the attributes you need?

Comment: @Chris How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: Hi, @vestland, yes, I was able to get your example to work; however, I don't think it will work with the px.sunburst attributes that I am using. I am especially interested in some of the more complex hovertemplate properties (in original post). I was unable to pass those properties to go.Sunburst without error. So I am kind of at a dead end here, unfortunately.

Comment: @Chris If you're able to share a sample of your data, then just maybe we can work it out.

Comment: @Chris `path`, for example, wasn't a problem to implement for another example. Just had to include the `ids` arguments like `ids=sb1[0]['ids']` and `ids=sb2[0]['ids']`. I don't see any reason why the other elements should not be able to implement as well...

Comment: @vestland, sure, just have df1 = pd.read_csv consume a file with the header line `LibPrefix,MasterPrefixAbrHead,MasterPrefixAbrTail,Drive,Population` and then just have the subsequent lines include 4 strings and then an integer, e.g. `lib1,A,B,D1,10`.

Comment: @vestland and then the second df2 - pd.read_scv would point to the same file format, but with different strings, e.g  `lib2,Z,V,D12,133`.

Comment: It is the hovertemplate that is causing the problems--its attributes are not understood by go.Sunburst. unless I am missing something.

Comment: @Chris I don't think hovertemplate should be a problem either. But that "sample" isn't much to work with. What you've got in your comment is rather a *description* of your data. Proper samples are usually regarded as a crucial element to a good question on SO. But I understand that the payoff might not outweigh the time and effort it takes to provide a proper data sample, so nevermind.

Comment: @vestland thanks for helping--it is much appreciated. The two lines of data I supplied are actually what's in the csv files, only there are another 1000 lines or so per file. If there is a way to point to the contents, I would happily make them available. But I am not sure how to do that in SO, and I don't have any public data that can be accessed via an html link.

Comment: @ChrisThere's rarely any need to share your *complete* dataset. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254) on how to share a *sample*

Answer (score 8):

Here's a modified version of @vestland's answer that makes use of subplots:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# data for px.sunburst1
data1 = dict(character=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
             parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve"],
             value=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4])

# data for px.sunburst2
data2 = dict(character=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos"],
             parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth"],
             value=[10, 14, 12, 10])

# extract data and structure FROM px.sunburst1
sb1 = px.sunburst(data1,
                  names='character',
                  parents='parent',
                  values='value',
                  )

# extract data and structure FROM px.sunburst2
sb2 = px.sunburst(data2,
                  names='character',
                  parents='parent',
                  values='value',
                  )

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[
    [{"type": "sunburst"}, {"type": "sunburst"}]
])

fig.add_trace(sb1.data[0], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(sb2.data[0], row=1, col=2)
fig.show()
```

Comment: That works very well ! Thanks.  @chris I suggest you to mark this one as the validated answer

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer

The following suggestion will show you how you can:

**1.** build two separate `px.Sunburst` figures, and

**2.** extract all necessary info regarding data and structure from them using `._data`, and

**3.**  use that to build two `go.Sunburst` traces, and

**4.** set them up side by side using the `domain` attribute.

In other words, you form your figures using `px.Sunburst`, and steal what you need from there to easily set up two sunburst diagrams side by side.

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code

```
import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px

# data for px.sunburst1
data1 = dict(character=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
             parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
             value=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4])

# data for px.sunburst2
data2 = dict(character=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos"],
             parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth" ],
             value=[10, 14, 12, 10])

# extract data and structure FROM px.sunburst1
sb1 =px.sunburst(data1,
                 names='character',
                 parents='parent',
                 values='value',
                )._data

# extract data and structure FROM px.sunburst2
sb2 =px.sunburst(data2,
                 names='character',
                 parents='parent',
                 values='value',
                )._data

# traces with separate domains to form a subplot
trace1 = go.Sunburst(labels=sb1[0]['labels'],
                        parents=sb1[0]['parents'],
                        values=sb1[0]['values'],
                        domain={'x': [0.0, 0.5], 'y': [0.0, 1]})

trace2 = go.Sunburst(labels=sb2[0]['labels'],
                        parents=sb2[0]['parents'],
                        values=sb2[0]['values'],
                        domain={'x': [0.5, 1.0], 'y': [0., 1.00]})

# layout and figure production
layout = go.Layout(height = 600,
                   width = 600,
                   autosize = False,
                   title = 'Side by side px.Sunburst diagrams')
fig = go.Figure(data = [trace1, trace2], layout = layout)
fig.show()
```