# Make 3D figure of 2D images "projecting information" onto each other

Tags: matplotlib, plotly, seaborn, data-visualization

Is there a way to make a z-stack of 2-D images, at the isometric view in 3-D, of points in each 2-D image projecting downwards to the next slice of 2-D images? I am certain there is a technical term for this, but I just don't have the vocabulary to find the most pertinent answer. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Below, I've drawn an "idea" of what this looks like. I'd love to know if this is possible without re-inventing wheels for `matplotlib` or other Python plotting libraries.

[image]

Comment: Interesting problem. Also, I think you should include some sample data.

Comment: @batlike Please spend the three minutes it takes to learn how to [share a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254) using `df.to_dict()`

Comment: Thanks, I realize it is not easy to copy/paste based on my format above. Thank you for this practice @vestland

Comment: @batlike No problem! It would be even better to do `df=pd.DataFrame(<you_dict>)` and include that it a runnable code snippet. But it's at least a start, and I switched my downvote to an upvote because of it =D

Comment: I think this is possible by messing around with [axis transforms](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html), specifically getting a transform which has some linear shear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question was posed for doing so in Python. After many months of searching, I found a way to do so in TikZ. I cannot consider this my original work, it is largely based on Pascal Seppecher's **interaction diagram** found here.

To reconstitute my question above, one can use the above template to define:

1. Agents of different shapes, specify fills
2. The frame (plane)
   which they reside in
3. Flows of directed edges that communicate
   how agents interact with each other in each plane
4. Inter-plane
   interaction flows

[image]

https://texample.net/tikz/examples/interaction-diagram/