# Plotly surface color change on individual lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly, data-science

### Problem statement:

Currently visualzing data points as lines on the Z-axis for a theory.

---

I am trying to make each line of this given 3D graphic have varying colors based on a model's decision (Binary Classification so two varying colors) and NOT on the values that exists inside the lines. (-4 to 4)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random
import pandas as pd

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=scaled[indexes])])
fig.update_traces(contours_z=dict(show=True, usecolormap=False,
                              project_z=True,))
fig.update_layout(title='3D', autosize=False,
                  scene_camera_eye=dict(x=1.87, y=0.88, z=-0.64),
                  width=1000, height=1000,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90),)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please [share a sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254) of your dataset.

Comment: A random data point array([ 1.,  0.70792366, -1.43985638, -0.04278498, 1.19324229,
        1.3768676 , -1.04399746,  0.70639621,  0.59804456]).

Comment: The given shape of the scaled data is (13230, 9).