# Python and pandas, groupby only column in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I would like to group some strings in the column called 'type' and insert them in a plotly bar, the problem is that from the new table created with groupby I can't extract the x and y to define them in the graph:

```
tipol1 = df.groupby(['tipology']).nunique()

tipol1
```

the outpot gives me tipology as index and the grouping based on how many times they repeat

```
         number data
typology  
  one     2      113
  two     33     33
  three   12     88
  four    44     888
  five    11     66
```

in the number column (in which I have other values ​​it gives me the correct grouping of the tipology column)
Also in the date column it gives me values ​​(I think grouping the dates but not the dates in the correct format)
I also found:

```
tipol=df.groupby(['tipology']).nunique()
tipol2 = tipol[['number']]
tipol2
```

to take only the number column,
but nothing to do, I would need the tipology column (not in index) and the column with the tipology grouping numbers to get the x and y axis to import it into plotly!

One last try I made (making a big mess):

```
tipol=df.groupby(['tipology'],as_index=False).nunique()
tipol2 = tipol[['number']]


fig = go.Figure(data=[
go.Bar(name='test', x=df['tipology'], y=tipol2)

])

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

any suggestions
thanks!

**UPDATE**

I would have too much code to give an example, it would be difficult for me and it would waste your time too. basically I would need a groupby with the addition of a column that would show the grouping value eg:

```
tipology    Date
home        10/01/18
home        11/01/18
garden      12/01/18
garden      12/01/18
garden      13/01/18
bathroom    13/01/18
bedroom     14/01/18
bedroom     15/01/18
kitchen     16/01/18
kitchen     16/01/18
kitchen     17/01/18
```

I wish this would happen:
by deleting the date column and inserting the value column in the DataFrame that does the count

```
tipology   value
home         2
garden       3
bathroom     1
bedroom      2
kitchen      3
```

Then (I'm working with jupyer notebook)
leaving the date column and adding the corresponding values ​​to the value column based on their grouping:

```
  tipology       Date     value
   home        10/01/18     1
   home        11/01/18     1
   garden      12/01/18     2
   garden      12/01/18_____.
   garden      13/01/18     1
   bathroom    13/01/18     1
   bedroom     14/01/18     1
   bedroom     15/01/18     1
   kitchen     16/01/18     2
   kitchen     16/01/18_____.
   kitchen     17/01/18     1
```

I would need the columns to assign them to the x and y axes to import them to a graph! so none of the columns should be index

Comment: `tipol1 = df.groupby(['tipology']).nunique().reset_index()`?

Comment: You can also use this convenient input of the group by `tipol1 = df.groupby('tipology', as_index=False).nunique()`

Comment: as I wrote in the comment of the answer, the column tipology after setting index to False returns numeric value (1 in this case)

Comment: @scofx Please consider sharing a sample of your data like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254), so that those seeking to provide a working suggestion don't have to spend all night recreating your challenge instead of creating an actual answer.

Comment: @vestland I made an update to the question to try to explain myself better!

Answer (score 0):

By default the method `groupby` will return a dataframe where the fields you are grouping on will be in the index of the dataframe. You can adjust this behaviour by setting `as_index=False` in the group by. Then `tipology` will still be a column in the dataframe that is returned:

```
tipol1 = df.groupby('tipology', as_index=False).nunique()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately the tipology column takes the numeric value 1 (setting index to False)

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you possibly update your code to exactly reproduce the problem?

Comment: I made an update to the question to try to explain myself better!