# Unable to plot bubble plot with right size

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, data-science, data-visualization, bubble-chart

I need to plot the Bubble Plot. But when output Bubble plot the marker size is exceptionally very big and unable to plot it clearly. I have used the following code for the purpose of plotting.

```
Afghanistan = go.Scatter(x = df4.Year, 
                        y = df4.Afghanistan, 
                        mode = 'markers',
                        marker_size = df4.Afghanistan,
                        marker=dict(
                            size=df4.Afghanistan,
                            color=df4.Afghanistan,
                            showscale=True))

data = [Afghanistan]

layout = go.Layout(title= 'Afghanistan',
                    xaxis= {'title' : 'My X-Axis'},
                    yaxis = dict(title = "My Y-Axis"),
                    hovermode = 'closest')

fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)

fig.show()
```

Below how the output looks like. the size of the markers are too big.
[image]

So how to reduce the size of the bubbles. (I have tried to reduce the bubble size, with the following commands also.. But not working)

```
size = 0.1 * df4.Afghanistan
```

Also tried with "normalize value", and mapped this "normalized value" for mapping size of the marker. Still output was the same.

```
    nor_Afghanistan = (df4.Afghanistan-df4['Afghanistan'].min())/(df4['Afghanistan'].max()-df4['Afghanistan'].min())
....
....
    size = nor_Afghanistan
```

Comment: Can you show us with `df4` looks like?

Comment: @viththi You can easily share your `df4` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254)