# Plotly add dropdown menu to figure

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am tryng to add a dropdown menu to a plotly express line chart. This menu will decide whereas the dates on the X axis group by day, month or year. This is the code I have by now:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

def group_dates_by_period(df, column, period):
    return df.groupby(df[column].dt.to_period(period))['Id Incidencia'].count()

periods = [('Día', 'D', '%Y-%m-%d'), ('Mes', 'M', '%Y-%m'), ('Año', 'Y', '%Y')]
fig2_data = group_dates_by_period(df, 'Fecha Apertura', periods[0][1])
fig2 = px.line(
                x=fig2_data.index.strftime(periods[0][2]),
                y=fig2_data.values,
                title='Distribución temporal de las incidencias',
                labels={
                    'x': 'Fecha',
                    'y': 'Nº incidencias'
                }
)

buttons = []
for period in periods:
    data = group_dates_by_period(df, 'Fecha Apertura', period[1])
    new_button = {
                    'method': 'restyle',
                    'label': period[0],
                    'args': [{
                                'y': data.values,
                                'x': data.index.strftime(period[2])
                    }]
    }
    buttons.append(new_button)

fig2.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(active=0, buttons=buttons)])
```

Although the "group-by day" data with which the chart is initialized is propertly drawn, when I click on  any of the dropdown options, the chart becomes blank with the X axis set to [-1,5].

The data returned by the "group_dates_by_period" function is correct, as if I initilize the chart with the group-by month or group-by year option it works as expected. So I guess it must be a problem with the dropdwon menu.

Data Sample:

```
{'index': [0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  9,
  10,
  11,
  12,
  13,
  14,
  15,
  16,
  17,
  18,
  19],
 'columns': ['Id Incidencia', 'Fecha Apertura'],
 'data': [['INC000006722157', Timestamp('2020-12-07 12:28:30')],
  ['INC000006722000', Timestamp('2020-12-07 09:52:06')],
  ['INC000006721939', Timestamp('2020-12-07 10:13:06')],
  ['INC000006708347', Timestamp('2020-12-02 09:02:45')],
  ['INC000006723090', Timestamp('2020-12-07 20:37:53')],
  ['INC000006736601', Timestamp('2020-12-12 00:35:16')],
  ['INC000006736721', Timestamp('2020-12-12 00:46:48')],
  ['INC000006724926', Timestamp('2020-12-08 15:21:15')],
  ['INC000006725331', Timestamp('2020-12-08 20:04:14')],
  ['INC000006725229', Timestamp('2020-12-08 18:33:54')],
  ['INC000006722542', Timestamp('2020-12-07 15:52:59')],
  ['INC000006722729', Timestamp('2020-12-07 18:33:22')],
  ['INC000006723246', Timestamp('2020-12-07 23:56:08')],
  ['INC000006722574', Timestamp('2020-12-07 17:11:05')],
  ['INC000006741563', Timestamp('2020-12-14 13:31:05')],
  ['INC000006722571', Timestamp('2020-12-07 17:06:55')],
  ['INC000006741632', Timestamp('2020-12-14 13:44:35')],
  ['INC000006741568', Timestamp('2020-12-14 13:33:40')],
  ['INC000006741636', Timestamp('2020-12-14 13:46:38')],
  ['INC000006741640', Timestamp('2020-12-14 13:51:34')]]}
```

Comment: Please include a data sample as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My dataset has sensitive content which I should not share, so here it is a little excerpt of it containing the two columns I use on the code: the timestamp and a row identifier. @vestland

Comment: That's better. Although it would be even better to include the data in your code snippet, and make sure that code and data runs well together.

Comment: Now I've checked, and they don't.