# Python Plotly express added trace won't animate

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly-express

I have one dataframe that produces two different bubbles on the same map by using traces. This works well to show on a specific day although when trying to animate both of these only fig1 will be animated and not the fig2. Is it possible to have both fig1 and fig2 to be animated based on the animation occurring in fig1?

```
covid = pd.read_csv('covid_19_data.csv')

fig1 = px.scatter_geo(covid, locations="Country/Region", locationmode="country names",animation_frame = "ObservationDate", hover_name = "Country/Region", size = "Confirmed", size_max = 60, projection= "natural earth")

fig2 = px.scatter_geo(covid, locations="Country/Region", locationmode="country names",animation_frame = "ObservationDate", hover_name = "Country/Region", size = "Tweets", size_max = 60, projection= "natural earth")

fig1.add_traces(fig2._data)

fig1.data[1].marker.color = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'

fig1.write_html('second.html', auto_open = True)
```

The current output from this code is the following map, where the animation frame is clear and works to increase the size and locations of the blue dots which represent cases ( fig1 ) and the red marker indicates tweets ( fig2 )
[image: Map output]

The dataframe I'm working with is:
[image]

Comment: *Please* share your datasample like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254). It's easy and will increase your chances of getting useful answers considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the data frames of the two figures in a single data frame and set the color as a class name like "Confirmed" & "Not Confirmed"

```
px.scatter_geo(covid, locations="Country/Region", locationmode="country names",animation_frame = "ObservationDate", hover_name = "Country/Region", size = "Single Class Size Column",color="Single Class Name Column" size_max = 60, projection= "natural earth")
```