# Markers with size 0 not visible in Plotly Express Scatter Plot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly.js

I am trying to draw a scatter plot with Plotly Express and facing a problem when setting the size of the markers. So this is the NumPy array that contains the numerical values in accordance to which, I want the marker size.

```
[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.53061224 0.65306122 0.28571429 1.
 0.48979592 0.53061224 0.         0.65306122]
```

When I set the arguments in

```py
px.scatter(size = size_array)
```

The markers on the plot with size 0 gets dissapeared, because literaly they have 0 size.

Is there any workaround this? So that markers which get 0 value are also visible on the plot?

I've attached the plot screenshot for reference, thanks.

[image: screenshot]

**EDIT**
I have replicated the whole issue here:
https://gist.github.com/SakshamSingh-v2/5eb27d728f572c97ad67a4e5def346c0

**Also**
One solution is to add a constant to the whole array, basically increasing the 0 to some value, but here the values represent severity. So increasing these values might give a mis-representation. I am thinking of a solution like in which I could map the 0 to some specified marker size.

Comment: Please share your complete code with imports. And preferrably a data sample of your data like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the `sizemin` attribute (in pixels!): https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-marker-sizemin

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Tried but I guess I didn't figure out how it works. So here is what I did, 
**fig = px.scatter(x = data['a'], y = data['b'], color = data['type'].astype(str), size = data['severity'], template = 'plotly_dark')
fig.update_traces(marker_sizemin = 0.1)
fig.show()**
But the 0's are still invisible. I've replicated the whole issue here, please go through this link: https://gist.github.com/SakshamSingh-v2/5eb27d728f572c97ad67a4e5def346c0

Comment: @SakshamSingh There shouldn't be any reason to go to an off-site resource to look into the details of your issues here. Please consider showing clearly ***in your question*** what you've tried, and also include a sample of your data. I've already provided a link on how to do that below your question.

Comment: `sizemin` is specified in *pixels*, so it's normal that 0.1 doesn't give you much. Try 5 or 10.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can copy that array and add constant value. So difference between initial values remain the same.

0            -> 1.00000000
0.53061224   -> 1.53061224

For hover information you can select your original array.

Comment: Actually, the values represent Severity, so if I add some constant and use that to represent, It might give a wrong insight as Severity 0 means completely well, and higher values show the increase. So I was thinking of an approach in which I can map a default marker size on 0. Thanks for the suggestion!