# Dash/plotly, show only top 10 values in histogram

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am creating a dashboard in dash for a course at university. I created 3 histograms however, there are many unique values which give a long range of x values. In my plots I would like to show only the 10 or 20 values that have the highest count (top 10 values). Can someone help me out?

```
import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
   html.H1("forensics "),
   dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
   dcc.Graph(id='graph1'),
   dcc.Graph(id='graph2'),
   html.Label([
        "select market",
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='market', clearable=False,
            value='whitehousemarket', options=[
                {'label': c, 'value': c}
                for c in posts['marketextract'].unique()
            ])
    ]),
])
# Define callback to update graph
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Output('graph1', 'figure'),
    Output('graph2', 'figure'),
    [Input("market", "value")]
)
def update_figure(market):
    fig=px.histogram(x=posts['datetime'].loc[posts['marketextract']==market])
    fig1=px.histogram(x=posts['username'].loc[posts['marketextract']==market])
    fig2=px.histogram(x=posts['drugs'].loc[posts['marketextract']==market])
    return [fig, fig1, fig2]



# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

[image]

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, `px.histogram()` does not have a method to exclude certain observations of bins. But judging by the *look* of your data (please consider sharing a [proper sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254)), what you're doing here is just showing the different counts of some user names. And you can easily do that through a combination of `df.groupby()` and `px.histogram`. Or `px.bar()` or `go.Bar()` for that matter, but we'll stick with `px.histogram` since that is what you're seeking help with. Anyway, using random selections of country names from `px.gapminder` you can use:

```
dfg = df.groupby(['name']).size().to_frame().sort_values([0], ascending = False).head(10).reset_index()
fig = px.histogram(dfg, x='name', y = 'count')
```

And get:

[image]

If you drop `.head(10)` you'll get this instead:

[image]

And I hope this is the sort of functionality you were looking for. And don't be intimidated by the long `df.groupby(['name']).size().to_frame().sort_values([0], ascending = False).reset_index()`. I'm not a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) expert, so you could quite possibly find a more efficient approach. But it does the job. Here's the complete code with some sample data:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import random

# data sample
gapminder = list(set(px.data.gapminder()['country']))[1:20]
names = random.choices(gapminder, k=100)

# data munging
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':names})
dfg = df.groupby(['name']).size().to_frame().sort_values([0], ascending = False).reset_index()
dfg.columns = ['name', 'count']

# plotly
fig = px.histogram(dfg, x='name', y = 'count')
fig.layout.yaxis.title.text = 'count'
fig.show()
```