# How to increase x ticks in plotly.express histogram

Tags: python, plotly

I have a Plotly graph with code:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.histogram(df.col1, width= 1500, height= 700)
fig.show()
```

and the plot looks like this:
[image]

### Is there a way I can increase the x tick markings to every 2 or 5 interval?

Tried:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.histogram(df.col1, width= 1500, height= 700)
fig.update_traces(xbins_size = 0.5)
fig.show()
```

and got
[image]

The issue is that I would like to increase x ticks to every 5 to improve visibility while capturing the range of 0-50. But the interval is still 10.

Comment: @nilsinlabore Don't forget your [data samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fig.update_traces(xbins_size = <float>)
```

---

For a plot built with:

```
fig = px.histogram(x=np.random.randn(500))
```

[image]

You can use:

```
fig.update_traces(xbins_size = 0.5)
```

And get:

[image]

Now, compare this with:

```
fig.update_traces(xbins_size = 1)
```

Which will give you:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
fig = px.histogram(x=np.random.randn(500))
fig.update_traces(xbins_size = 0.5)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Hi vestland, thank you for the answer. I had a bit issue which I added in my update, could you please have a look?