# How to add more descriptions to the y-axis in a plotly.express timeline

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

How can I add more text or columns to the y-axis in a `plotly.express` timeline visualization?

[image]

to get something like this: is this possible?
[image]

sample code with only three drugs:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

sample= {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'columns': ['row_id', 'subject_id', 'hadm_id', 'icustay_id', 'startdate', 'enddate', 'drug_type', 'drug', 'drug_name_poe', 'drug_name_generic', 'formulary_drug_cd', 'gsn', 'ndc', 'prod_strength', 'dose_val_rx', 'dose_unit_rx', 'form_val_disp', 'form_unit_disp', 'route'], 'data': [[32600, 42458, 159647, 'nan', '2146-07-21 00:00:00', '2146-07-25 00:00:00', 'MAIN', 'Pneumococcal Vac Polyvalent', 'Pneumococcal Vac Polyvalent', 'PNEUMOcoccal Vac Polyvalent', 'PNEU25I', 48548.0, 6494300.0, '25mcg/0.5mL Vial', '0.5', 'mL', '1', 'VIAL', 'IM'], [32601, 42458, 159647, 'nan', '2146-07-21 00:00:00', '2146-08-22 00:00:00', 'MAIN', 'Bisacodyl', 'Bisacodyl', 'Bisacodyl', 'BISA5', 2947.0, 536338101.0, '5 mg Tab', '10', 'mg', '2', 'TAB', 'PO'], [32602, 42458, 159647, 'nan', '2146-07-21 00:00:00', '2146-07-22 00:00:00', 'MAIN', 'Bisacodyl', 'Bisacodyl', 'Bisacodyl (Rectal)', 'BISA10R', 2944.0, 574705050.0, '10mg Suppository', '10', 'mg', '1', 'SUPP', 'PR'], [32603, 42458, 159647, 'nan', '2146-07-21 00:00:00', '2146-07-22 00:00:00', 'MAIN', 'Senna', 'Senna', 'Senna', 'SENN187', 19964.0, 904516561.0, '1 Tablet', '1', 'TAB', '1', 'TAB', 'PO'], [32604, 42458, 159647, 'nan', '2146-07-21 00:00:00', '2146-07-21 00:00:00', 'MAIN', 'Docusate Sodium (Liquid)', 'Docusate Sodium (Liquid)', 'Docusate Sodium (Liquid)', 'DOCU100L', 3017.0, 121054410.0, '100mg UD Cup', '100', 'mg', '1', 'UDCUP', 'PO']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(index=sample['index'], columns=sample['columns'], data=sample['data'])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="startdate", x_end="enddate", y="drug")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.show()
```

Thank you

Comment: @KTTRLD Please don't share a data sample as an image. There are other and [better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [tick formatting](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/) can be used `"tickmode": "array",`
- use a **list comprehension** to lookup the additional columns
- clearly this is a proxy,  it does not inject a table.  It modifies the **ticktext** as a longer string

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=sample["index"], columns=sample["columns"], data=sample["data"])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="startdate", x_end="enddate", y="drug")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
# create a data frame to lookup additional columns.  NB there are duplicates!
dfl = (
    df.loc[:, ["drug", "drug_name_generic", "prod_strength"]]
    .copy()
    .set_index("drug", drop=False)
    .drop_duplicates(subset="drug")
)
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis={
        "tickmode": "array",
        "tickvals": fig.data[0].y,
        "ticktext": [" - ".join(dfl.loc[y]) for y in fig.data[0].y],
    }
)
fig
```

Comment: Ok, the longer string is of course not perfect but i guess it is the only way. Thank you for the answer.