# Python function returning multiple graphs is not working

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am creating a function that returns multiple graphs (a total of 9 nos). I need to see the graphs in plotlys dashboard. when I am running the code a blank graph is coming. Please see the attached image. I am expecting 9 different graphs on that webpage.

Please see my code below. May I know where I went wrong? My sample data set is available here[[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68265640/live-updating-graph-in-plotly-dash).

Please see my code below

```
    import plotly as py
    import plotly
    import cufflinks as cf
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode,plot, iplot
    init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
    cf.go_offline()
    
    import dash
    import dash_core_components as dcc
    import dash_html_components as html
    from dash.dependencies import Input,Output
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    app = dash.Dash(__name__)
    
    def _create_fig():
        
        df_Noise=pd.read_csv('Funct_Noise_Corners_2p0_A.txt',delim_whitespace=True)
        df_noise_50 = df_Noise[(df_Noise['Temp(deg)'] == -20)| (df_Noise['Temp(deg)'] == 25)| (df_Noise['Temp(deg)'] == 50)]
        df_50_08_16 = df_noise_50[(df_noise_50['Frequency[MHz]'] == 0.8)| (df_noise_50['Frequency[MHz]'] == 1.6)]
        df_50_08_16_PVT=pd.pivot_table(df_50_08_16, index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)' ,'Supply[V]'],columns='Frequency[MHz]',values = 'NoiseLevel[dB]')
        df_50_08_16_PVT['SPEC_MAX']=-96.5
        fig0=df_50_08_16_PVT.iplot(asFigure=True,title='NOISE@_0.8Mhz_1.6MhzTemp_Range_Upto_50Deg')
        
        df_50_04_24_48 = df_noise_50[(df_noise_50['Frequency[MHz]'] == 2.4)| (df_noise_50['Frequency[MHz]'] == 4.8)| (df_noise_50['Frequency[MHz]'] == 0.4)]
        df_50_04_24_48_PVT=pd.pivot_table(df_50_04_24_48 , index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)' ,'Supply[V]'],columns='Frequency[MHz]',values = 'NoiseLevel[dB]')
        df_50_04_24_48_PVT['SPEC_MAX']=-99.5
        fig1=df_50_04_24_48_PVT.iplot(asFigure=True,title='NOISE@_0.4Mhz_2.4Mhz_4.8Mhz_Temp_Range_Upto_50Deg')
        
        df_8_16 = df_Noise[(df_Noise['Frequency[MHz]'] == 0.8)| (df_Noise['Frequency[MHz]'] == 1.6)]
        df_8_16_PVT=pd.pivot_table(df_8_16 , index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)' ,'Supply[V]'],columns='Frequency[MHz]',values = 'NoiseLevel[dB]')
        df_8_16_PVT['SPEC_MAX']=-96.5
        fig2=df_8_16_PVT.iplot(asFigure=True,title='NOISE@_0.8Mhz_1.6Mhz_All_Temp_Range')
        
        df_04_24_48 = df_Noise[(df_Noise['Frequency[MHz]'] == 2.4)| (df_Noise['Frequency[MHz]'] == 4.8)| (df_Noise['Frequency[MHz]'] == 0.4)]
        df_04_24_48_PVT=pd.pivot_table(df_04_24_48 , index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)' ,'Supply[V]'],columns = 'Frequency[MHz]',values = 'NoiseLevel[dB]')
        df_04_24_48_PVT['SPEC_MAX']=-99.5
        fig3=df_04_24_48_PVT.iplot(asFigure=True,title='NOISE@_0.4Mhz_2.4Mhz_4.8Mhz_All_Temp_Range')
        
        df_TDEN=pd.read_csv('Funct_TDEN_Corners_2p0_A.txt',delim_whitespace=True)
        df_TDEN_PVT = pd.pivot_table(df_TDEN, index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)' ,'Supply[V]'],columns='Frequency[MHz]',values =['TDEN_Rise[ns]','TDEN_Fall[ns]'] )
        df_TDEN_PVT['SPEC_MAX']=80
        df_TDEN_PVT['SPEC_MIN']=50
        fig4=df_TDEN_PVT.iplot(asFigure=True,title='TDEN_CAP_LOAD_50pF')
        
        df_RT_FT_04=df_TDEN[(df_TDEN['Frequency[MHz]'] == 0.4)]
        df_RT_FT_04_PVT = pd.pivot_table(df_RT_FT_04,index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)' ,'Supply[V]','Frequency[MHz]'],values =['Risetime[ns]','Falltime[ns]'] )
        fig5=df_RT_FT_04_PVT.iplot(asFigure=True,title='RT_FT_0.4Mhz_LOAD_50pF')
        
        df_RT_FT_24=df_TDEN[(df_TDEN['Frequency[MHz]'] == 2.4)]
        df_RT_FT_24_PVT = pd.pivot_table(df_RT_FT_24,index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)' ,'Supply[V]','Frequency[MHz]'],values =['Risetime[ns]','Falltime[ns]'] )
        df_RT_FT_24_PVT['SPEC_MAX']=80
        df_RT_FT_24_PVT['SPEC_MIN']=40
        fig6=df_RT_FT_24_PVT.iplot(asFigure=True,title='RT_FT_2.4Mhz_LOAD_50pF')
        
        df_RT_FT_37=df_TDEN[(df_TDEN['Frequency[MHz]'] == 3.07)]
        df_RT_FT_37_PVT = pd.pivot_table(df_RT_FT_37,index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)' ,'Supply[V]','Frequency[MHz]'],values =['Risetime[ns]','Falltime[ns]'] )
        df_RT_FT_37_PVT['SPEC_MAX'] =35
        df_RT_FT_37_PVT['SPEC_MIN'] =23
        fig7=df_RT_FT_37_PVT.iplot(asFigure=True,title='RT_FT_3.07Mhz_LOAD_50pF')
        
        df_TDH_RT=pd.read_csv('Funct_TDH_RISE_Corners_2p0_A.txt',delim_whitespace=True)
        df_TDH_RT_PVT = pd.pivot_table(df_TDH_RT,index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp(deg)' ,'Supply[V]'],columns='Frequency[MHz]',values =['TDH_Rise[ns]'] )
        df_TDH_RT_PVT['SPEC_MIN']=5
        df_TDH_RT_PVT['SPEC_MAX']=30 
        fig8 = df_TDH_RT_PVT.iplot(asFigure=True,title='TDH_RISE',width=3)   
     
    
        
        fig=[fig0,fig1,fig2,fig3,fig4,fig5,fig6,fig7,fig8]    
           
        return fig
    
    app.layout = html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='g1',
            figure=_create_fig()),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        )
    ])
    
    
    @app.callback(
        dash.dependencies.Output('g1', 'figure'),
        dash.dependencies.Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
    def refresh_data(n_clicks):
        return _create_fig()
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run_server()
```

The graph obtained by using the above code

[image]

Comment: Please include all necessary data samples ***in*** your question, and not links to raw data contained in another post. There are several ways you can do this. I find [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254) to be the most useful.

Comment: May i know any issue in my function.When the function gets called no graph is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you'll be able to find more hints for any errors in your Dash code if you run the server in your main using `app.run_server(debug=True)` while developing.

In your case, you should see an error message like this:

```
Invalid argument `figure` passed into Graph with ID "g1".
Expected `object`.
Was supplied type `array`.
```

And indeed, you are passing a list of figures as `figure` to your `dcc.Graph` object with `id=g1`. Howver, this can only be a single figure, not a list of them.

Some suggestions for alternative approaches to fix this:

1. Use `plotly.subplots.make_subplots` to create a single figure where each of your current 9 figures is a single subplots.
2. Use multiple `dcc.Graph` objects in your layout, one per figure.
3. If you don't need to access the graphs at any other point in the code, you could create 9 `dcc.Graph` objects in and pass them as a list to a container `Div` in your layout.

Whatever you choose to try, I suggest trying it with some dummy data first and only start incorporating "real" data once you figured out the basic layout.

Comment: Thank you.will try the methods suggested and update you tomorrow.

Comment: ,I made changes as you suggested now it is working.Thank you