# Weird Time-Series Graph Using Pycaret and plotly

Tags: python, time-series, plotly, pycaret

I am trying to visualize Air Quality Data as time-series charts using pycaret and plotly dash python libraries , but i am getting very weird graphs, below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
data = pd.read_csv('E:/Self Learning/Djang_Dash/2019-2020_5.csv')
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
#data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)


# combine store and item column as time_series
data['OBJECTID'] = ['Location_' + str(i) for i in data['OBJECTID']]
#data['AQI_Bins_AI'] = ['Bin_' + str(i) for i in data['AQI_Bins_AI']]
data['time_series'] = data[['OBJECTID']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x), axis=1)
data.drop(['OBJECTID'], axis=1, inplace=True)
# extract features from date
data['month'] = [i.month for i in data['Date']]
data['year'] = [i.year for i in data['Date']]
data['day_of_week'] = [i.dayofweek for i in data['Date']]
data['day_of_year'] = [i.dayofyear for i in data['Date']]
data.head(4000)

data['time_series'].nunique()


for i in data['time_series'].unique():
    subset = data[data['time_series'] == i]
    subset['moving_average'] = subset['CO'].rolling(window = 30).mean()
    fig = px.line(subset, x="Date", y=["CO","moving_average"], title = i, template = 'plotly_dark')
    fig.show()
```

[image: here is my weird output graph]

require needful help in this regard,

here is my sample data [Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-s21Iv6O1gV2BBVvfr8C4zsUUCZl1cnL/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is each piece of data in the format of date data? Also, can you try adding this and see if it improves things? `fig.update_xaxes(type='date')`

Comment: @eirsh Please make your challenge reproducible by sharing a sample of your data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254). Otherwise any suggestion for improvements would be pure speculation.

Comment: @vestland i have edited the question and provided with sample data, please have a look.

Comment: @eirsh As described in the provided link, please. `df.tail(25).to_dict()`, copy, and paste into `df = pd.DataFrame(your_dict)`.

Comment: @vestland thanks, please check now i have edited the question with updated sample data

Comment: @eirsh Include `df=pd.DataFrame(...)` ***with*** that output ***in*** your code and make sure that your entire code snippet is runnable and reproduces your problem, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- data has not been provided in a usable way.  Sought out publicly available similar data.  found: https://www.kaggle.com/rohanrao/air-quality-data-in-india?select=station_hour.csv
- using this data, with a couple of cleanups of your code, no issues with plots.  I suspect your data has one of these issues

  1. date is not `datetime64[ns]` in your data frame
  2. date is not sorted, leading to lines being drawn in way you have noted
- by refactoring way moving average is calculated, you can use animation instead of lots of separate figures

#### get some data

```
import kaggle.cli
import sys, math
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import plotly.express as px

# download data set
# https://www.kaggle.com/rohanrao/air-quality-data-in-india?select=station_hour.csv
sys.argv = [
    sys.argv[0]
] + "datasets download rohanrao/air-quality-data-in-india".split(
    " "
)
kaggle.cli.main()

zfile = ZipFile("air-quality-data-in-india.zip")
print([f.filename for f in zfile.infolist()])
```

#### plot using code from question

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from pathlib import Path
from distutils.version import StrictVersion

# data = pd.read_csv('E:/Self Learning/Djang_Dash/2019-2020_5.csv')
# use kaggle data
# dfs = {f.filename:pd.read_csv(zfile.open(f)) for f in zfile.infolist() if f.filename in ['station_day.csv',"stations.csv"]}
# data = pd.merge(dfs['station_day.csv'],dfs["stations.csv"], on="StationId")

# data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
# # kaggle data is different from question, make it compatible with questions data
# data = data.assign(OBJECTID=lambda d: d["StationId"])

# sample data from google drive link
data2 = pd.read_csv(Path.home().joinpath("Downloads").joinpath("AQI.csv"))
data2["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data2["Date"])

data = data2
# as per very first commment - it's important data is ordered !
data = data.sort_values(["Date","OBJECTID"])
data['time_series'] = "Location_" + data["OBJECTID"].astype(str)
# clean up data, remove rows where there is no CO value
data = data.dropna(subset=["CO"])
# can do moving average in one step (can also be used by animation)
if StrictVersion(pd.__version__) < StrictVersion("1.3.0"):
    data["moving_average"] = data.groupby("time_series",as_index=False)["CO"].rolling(window=30).mean().to_frame()["CO"].values
else:
    data["moving_average"] = data.groupby("time_series",as_index=False)["CO"].rolling(window=30).mean()["CO"]

# just first two for purpose of demonstration
for i in data['time_series'].unique()[0:3]:
    subset = data.loc[data['time_series'] == i]
    fig = px.line(subset, x="Date", y=["CO","moving_average"], title = i, template = 'plotly_dark')
    fig.show()
```

#### can use animation

```
px.line(
    data,
    x="Date",
    y=["CO", "moving_average"],
    animation_frame="time_series",
    template="plotly_dark",
).update_layout(yaxis={"range":[data["CO"].min(), data["CO"].quantile(.97)]})
```

[image]

Comment: what this line is doing `data = data.assign(OBJECTID=lambda d: d["StationId"])` , i am getting this error `KeyError: 'CO' `

Comment: the data from kaggle, has a column **StationID**,  your plot code has a column **OBJECTID**,  just assigning one to the other to make data sets structurally equivalent.  i.e. ensure kaggle data has a column called **OBJECTID**

Comment: that error does not correspnd to that line,  the key it is complaining about is **CO**.  provide your sample data as usable,  if it contains ellipses ("...") it is unusable

Comment: yes error belongs to this line `data["moving_average"] = data.groupby("time_series",as_index=False)["CO"].rolling(window=30).mean()["CO"]` , while `CO` is present in my data frame

Comment: `data.columns` any trailing spaces?  pandas version (don't think it will be this) `pd.__version__`?

Comment: i am trying to run the animation code as well which you have provided and giving this error --> All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y` is 2, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['Date'] is 77616

Comment: no trailing spaces exist `Index(['OBJECTID', 'X', 'Y', 'Date', 'AI', 'CO', 'NO2', 'SO2', 'O3',
       'AQI_Bins_AI', 'AQI_Bins_CO', 'AQI_Bins_NO2', 'AQI_Bins_O3',
       'AQI_Bins_SO2', 'geom', 'Province', 'Province.1', 'time_series',
       'month', 'year', 'day_of_week', 'day_of_year'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: are you using the kaggle data set?

Comment: no i am mapping your provided code on my dataset, glimpse of that data i have shown in the question.

Comment: let's switch to chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236833/weird-time-series-graph-using-pycaret-and-plotly

Comment: i do not have sufficient reputation to chat with you i require at least 20

Comment: ok - update your question with output of `data.head(40).to_dict("list")` and I'll take a look at it

Comment: beg my pardon, please check the data, i have just edited the question with data in dictionary (list). i do not know is that in correct format which you required..

Comment: data required quite a lot of work to make it usable.  sample date should not have line continuation characters and line breaks between string delimiters.  what I can find after fixing it up... sample data is no good for plotting as it is only one day. had to modify one line of code as **OBJECTID"" in a number `data['time_series'] = "Location_" + data["OBJECTID"].astype(str)`.  this line of code does work `data["moving_average"] = data.groupby("time_series",as_index=False)["CO"].rolling(window=30).mean()["CO"]` but pointless as the sample data is only one day.

Comment: you will see I've reformatted sample data in question to make it possible to be a simple copy.   I suggest provide sample by data.loc[data["OBJECTID"].isin(16589, 16590)].to_dict("list")` and make it useable :-).

Comment: May I add the Google Drive link of the Data in question? Rather Data Dictionary as my data is not getting fit into the body of question. My question charecters are increasing from 300000 limit.

Comment: perfect - just add to comment and I'll pick it up.  then you can delete later if you don't want to leave access to it

Comment: Thanks dear i have edited the question with google drive link, please see if you got the data. You are pro

Comment: access denied on that link

Comment: Sorry, Please check now please

Comment: updated answer to use your data.  you only really had one problem - data was not sorted.  anyway both creating three plots and a plot with animation work and provide sensible lines when ordered.   I thought that had been noted.  I'm using pandas 1.3.2 and plotly 5.2.2

Comment: Key error 'CO' while executing this line of code `data["moving_average"] = data.groupby("time_series",as_index=False)['CO'].rolling(window=30).mean()['CO']`

Comment: versions please...  pandas specifically - I have restarted my kernel multiple times to ensure no issues

Comment: sorry for being late dear, `pandas version= 1.2.4 and plotly= 5.1.0` , which you have acquired from me in last message.

Comment: updated answer...  simplest is to upgrade pandas,  there is a change in behaviour of pandas between 1.2.4 and 1.3.2 so code now checks version and runs different things based on version number

Comment: I have no words to say you Thank you I wish i could upvote for your each comment , Thanks Alot its finally working ,