# Python polar plot ordering of data?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, plotly

I am creating a polar plot with the following code.

```
import plotly as pt
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('newdata.csv')

range_num = list(range(100,181, 5))
options = ['NOT_VISIBLE', 'NOT_POSSIBLE', 'ABOVE_LIMIT']
all_options = incompletes + ([str(num) for num in range_num])

dfnew = df.drop(['IDENT', 'LOCATION', 'MONTH', 'AGE'], axis = 1)

df['PT'] = dfnew.ffill(axis='columns').iloc[:, -1]
data = df.groupby('AGE')['PT'].value_counts().reset_index(name='COUNT')

fig = px.line_polar(data, r="COUNT", theta="PT", color="AGE", line_close=True,
                    color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.show()
```

This shows a polar plot with two sets of data being plotted for AGE=YES and AGE=NO (YES and NO being the two values in the AGE column). My issue here is that the data around the polar plot is disorganised. I would like the top to start with `NOT_VISIBLE` then going clockwise, follow with `NOT_POSSIBLE` `ABOVE_LIMIT` and the numbers in ascending order (100, 105, 110 etc).

I am sure there is a straightforward way to do this but I am new to python and can't seem to figure it out.

I tried to do:

```
SC = sorted(['PT'])
```

But this has not worked, not sure what else to try, any help is greatly appreciated.

Python 2.7 and PANDAS 0.24.2

EDIT: Data below (Actual data contains a lot more rows).

```
pd.DataFrame({'IDENT': {0L: 'ID76', 1L: 'ID34', 2L: 'ID51', 3L: 'ID97', 4L: 'ID73', 5L: 'ID14', 6L: 'ID64', 7L: 'ID10', 8L: 'ID32', 9L: 'ID89', 10L: 'ID27', 11L: 'ID19', 12L: 'ID80', 13L: 'ID71', 14L: 'ID08', 15L: 'ID47', 16L: 'ID66', 17L: 'ID23'}, 'AGE': {0L: 'YES', 1L: 'NO', 2L: 'YES', 3L: 'NO', 4L: 'NO', 5L: 'NO', 6L: 'YES', 7L: 'YES', 8L: 'YES', 9L: 'NO', 10L: 'YES', 11L: 'YES', 12L: 'NO', 13L: 'YES', 14L: 'NO', 15L: 'NO', 16L: 'YES', 17L: 'YES'}, 'MONTH': {0L: 1990L, 1L: 2000L, 2L: 2010L, 3L: 2020L, 4L: 2020L, 5L: 2010L, 6L: 2000L, 7L: 1990L, 8L: 2020L, 9L: 2010L, 10L: 1990L, 11L: 2020L, 12L: 2000L, 13L: 2010L, 14L: 1990L, 15L: 2020L, 16L: 2000L, 17L: 1990L}, 'LOCATION': {0L: 'E1', 1L: 'E4', 2L: 'E2', 3L: 'E1', 4L: 'E3', 5L: 'E4', 6L: 'E3', 7L: 'E1', 8L: 'E2', 9L: 'E1', 10L: 'E2', 11L: 'E3', 12L: 'E2', 13L: 'E1', 14L: 'E4', 15L: 'E3', 16L: 'E4', 17L: 'E2'}, 'PT5': {0L: nan, 1L: 'ABOVE_LIMIT', 2L: nan, 3L: nan, 4L: nan, 5L: nan, 6L: nan, 7L: nan, 8L: '100', 9L: nan, 10L: nan, 11L: nan, 12L: 'NOT_POSSIBLE', 13L: nan, 14L: nan, 15L: nan, 16L: '165', 17L: 'NOT_POSSIBLE'}, 'PT4': {0L: '110', 1L: nan, 2L: '145', 3L: nan, 4L: 'NOT_VISIBLE', 5L: nan, 6L: '105', 7L: nan, 8L: nan, 9L: nan, 10L: 'ABOVE_LIMIT', 11L: nan, 12L: nan, 13L: nan, 14L: 'NOT_VISIBLE', 15L: nan, 16L: nan, 17L: '130'}, 'PT3': {0L: nan, 1L: 'NOT_POSSIBLE', 2L: nan, 3L: nan, 4L: nan, 5L: nan, 6L: nan, 7L: 'NOT_POSSIBLE', 8L: nan, 9L: nan, 10L: nan, 11L: 'NOT_VISIBLE', 12L: nan, 13L: nan, 14L: nan, 15L: nan, 16L: nan, 17L: nan}, 'PT2': {0L: nan, 1L: nan, 2L: nan, 3L: '160', 4L: nan, 5L: nan, 6L: nan, 7L: '180', 8L: 'NOT_VISIBLE', 9L: nan, 10L: '160', 11L: nan, 12L: nan, 13L: nan, 14L: nan, 15L: nan, 16L: nan, 17L: 'ABOVE_LIMIT'}, 'PT1': {0L: nan, 1L: nan, 2L: nan, 3L: nan, 4L: 'ABOVE_LIMIT', 5L: nan, 6L: nan, 7L: nan, 8L: nan, 9L: nan, 10L: nan, 11L: nan, 12L: '115', 13L: nan, 14L: nan, 15L: nan, 16L: nan, 17L: nan}})


+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| IDENT | LOCATION | AGE | MONTH | PT1  | PT2  | PT3   | PT4  | PT5          |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID76  | E1       | YES | 1990  |      |      |       | 110  |              |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID34  | E4       | NO  | 2000  |      |      | NOT_POSSIBLE | ABOVE_LIMIT  |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID51  | E2       | YES | 2010  |      |      |       | 145  |              |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID97  | E1       | NO  | 2020  |      | 160  |       |      |              |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID73  | E3       | NO  | 2020  | ABOVE_LIMIT |       | NOT_VISIBLE         |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID14  | E4       | NO  | 2010  |      |      |       |      |              |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID64  | E3       | YES | 2000  |      |      |       | 105  |              |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID10  | E1       | YES | 1990  |      | 180  | NOT_POSSIBLE |              |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID32  | E2       | YES | 2020  |      | NOT_VISIBLE  |      | 100          |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID89  | E1       | NO  | 2010  |      |      |       |      |              |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID27  | E2       | YES | 1990  |      | 160  |       | ABOVE_LIMIT         |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID19  | E3       | YES | 2020  |      |      | NOT_VISIBLE  |              |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID80  | E2       | NO  | 2000  | 115  |      |       |      | NOT_POSSIBLE |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID71  | E1       | YES | 2010  |      |      |       |      |              |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID08  | E4       | NO  | 1990  |      |      |       | NOT_VISIBLE         |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID47  | E3       | NO  | 2020  |      |      |       |      |              |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID66  | E4       | YES | 2000  |      |      |       |      | 165          |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+------+-------+------+--------------+
| ID23  | E2       | YES | 1990  |      | ABOVE_LIMIT  | 130  | NOT_POSSIBLE |
+-------+----------+-----+-------+------+--------------+------+--------------+
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your data as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254) in order to make your code reproducible.

Comment: Thank you, initial question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

- not sure if this will work with python 2. I really recommend your upgrade to python 3. Python 2 has been end of life since 1-Jan-2020
- you need to sort your data in order for axis to work way you want

  1. have used python `sorted()` to define ordered list of **PT**
  2. have used [pandas categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) to enable sorting using custom order defined in 1.
  3. have done an optional step of making **data** a product of valid combinations of **AGE** and **PT**.  without this order with be set by first trace then missing values appended (rather than ordered)

```
import plotly as pt
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'IDENT': {0: 'ID76', 1: 'ID34', 2: 'ID51', 3: 'ID97', 4: 'ID73', 5: 'ID14', 6: 'ID64', 7: 'ID10', 8: 'ID32', 9: 'ID89', 10: 'ID27', 11: 'ID19', 12: 'ID80', 13: 'ID71', 14: 'ID08', 15: 'ID47', 16: 'ID66', 17: 'ID23'}, 'AGE': {0: 'YES', 1: 'NO', 2: 'YES', 3: 'NO', 4: 'NO', 5: 'NO', 6: 'YES', 7: 'YES', 8: 'YES', 9: 'NO', 10: 'YES', 11: 'YES', 12: 'NO', 13: 'YES', 14: 'NO', 15: 'NO', 16: 'YES', 17: 'YES'}, 'MONTH': {0: 1990, 1: 2000, 2: 2010, 3: 2020, 4: 2020, 5: 2010, 6: 2000, 7: 1990, 8: 2020, 9: 2010, 10: 1990, 11: 2020, 12: 2000, 13: 2010, 14: 1990, 15: 2020, 16: 2000, 17: 1990}, 'LOCATION': {0: 'E1', 1: 'E4', 2: 'E2', 3: 'E1', 4: 'E3', 5: 'E4', 6: 'E3', 7: 'E1', 8: 'E2', 9: 'E1', 10: 'E2', 11: 'E3', 12: 'E2', 13: 'E1', 14: 'E4', 15: 'E3', 16: 'E4', 17: 'E2'}, 'PT5': {0: nan, 1: 'ABOVE_LIMIT', 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: '100', 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: 'NOT_POSSIBLE', 13: nan, 14: nan, 15: nan, 16: '165', 17: 'NOT_POSSIBLE'}, 'PT4': {0: '110', 1: nan, 2: '145', 3: nan, 4: 'NOT_VISIBLE', 5: nan, 6: '105', 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: 'ABOVE_LIMIT', 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan, 14: 'NOT_VISIBLE', 15: nan, 16: nan, 17: '130'}, 'PT3': {0: nan, 1: 'NOT_POSSIBLE', 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: 'NOT_POSSIBLE', 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: 'NOT_VISIBLE', 12: nan, 13: nan, 14: nan, 15: nan, 16: nan, 17: nan}, 'PT2': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: '160', 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: '180', 8: 'NOT_VISIBLE', 9: nan, 10: '160', 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan, 14: nan, 15: nan, 16: nan, 17: 'ABOVE_LIMIT'}, 'PT1': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 'ABOVE_LIMIT', 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: '115', 13: nan, 14: nan, 15: nan, 16: nan, 17: nan}})

# env setup
incompletes = []

range_num = list(range(100,181, 5))
options = ['NOT_VISIBLE', 'NOT_POSSIBLE', 'ABOVE_LIMIT']
all_options = incompletes + ([str(num) for num in range_num])

dfnew = df.drop(['IDENT', 'LOCATION', 'MONTH', 'AGE'], axis = 1)

df['PT'] = dfnew.ffill(axis='columns').iloc[:, -1]
data = df.groupby('AGE')['PT'].value_counts().reset_index(name='COUNT')

# define custom ordered list of unique PT values
orderpt = sorted(
    data["PT"].unique().tolist(),
    key=lambda x: options.index(x) if x in options else int(x)
)

# optional - make sure all combinations of AGE & PT are in data set
data = data.merge(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [["YES", "NO"], pd.Categorical(orderpt, ordered=True)], names=["AGE", "PT"]
    )
    .to_frame()
    .reset_index(drop=True),
    on=["AGE", "PT"],
    how="right"
).fillna(0)

# redefine PT as a categorical that uses custom order
data["PT"] = pd.Categorical(data["PT"], categories=orderpt, ordered=True)

fig = px.line_polar(data.sort_values(["AGE","PT"]), r="COUNT", theta="PT", color="AGE", line_close=True,
                    color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.show()
```

[image]