# Pandas - Add value to a Column on a For

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying a script and i want to add value to each row on my Column login:

If the result on For is 200 i want add "yes" to the login Column on the correct row.

thank u!

```
import pandas as pd
from requests import get
lista = pd.read_csv('sites.csv', sep=',')
df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns=['Site', 'Login'])
newdf = df.assign(Site=df['Site'].map(str) + 'login')


for i in newdf['Site']:
    result = get(i)
    if result.status_code == 200:
        print(i + '' ' login page')
    elif result.status_code == 404:
        print(i + '' ' not a login page')
    else :
        print(i + '' ' Not a login page')enter code here
```

the csv data:

```
Site, Login
https://www.site1.com.br/,
https://www.site2.com.br/,
https://www.site3.com.br/,
```

Comment: Can you replicate a sample of your data, so community can answer your question better. you can use `df.head(10).to_dict(orient='list')`

Comment: @ashkangh  you mean the CSV?

Comment: No no! I mean when you read your csv data file, and you have your dataframe (whose name is df), you can use above command to print a 10 rows of your data, and you can add that data(which will be as a dictionary) to your question. you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63163254/13131320)

Comment: Another thing, you should avoid using `for` loops in pandas since the ability of pandas is to enjoy vectorized calculations. In fact, in most cases, pandas has methods and functions that serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do it in one single line using `apply`:

```
newdf['login'] = newdf['Site'].apply(lambda x : "yes" if get(x).status_code == 200 else "no")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to just iterate over the rows and add it in that way:

```
for i in range(newdf.shape[0]):
   result = get(newdf.iloc[i,0])
   if result == 200:
      newdf.iloc[i,1] = "yes"
```

etc.

Comment: i got you! it should work but the return is 

for i in range(newdf.shape()[0]):
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: My bad, it's a typo. Just fixed it.