# Plotly histogram change colors for the bars associated with different values

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following plotly histogram, where I want to show the distribution of the values for a variable which can have only two categorical values:

[image]

I am currently plotting it with
`fig = px.histogram(pd.DataFrame(hist_data, columns=['result']), x="result", histfunc='count', histnorm='probability density'`) and the plot is correct, but both bins are blue and I would like to have them of two different colors.
So I tried to do the following:
`fig = px.histogram(pd.DataFrame(hist_data, columns=['result']), x="result", histfunc='count', histnorm='probability density', color="result", color_discrete_map={value1: color1, value2: color2})`
In this way the two bars are correctly colored, but the plot is not anymore correct!

[image]

The two bars have both value 1, they don't represent anymore the distribution of the values of the variable result.

edit: for maximum clearness, `hist_data` is a list containing only `no disease` or `cardiovascular disease` as values:

```
hist_data = ['no disease',
 'cardiovascular disease',
 'no disease',
 'no disease',
 'cardiovascular disease',
 'cardiovascular disease',
 'cardiovascular disease',
 'cardiovascular disease',
 'cardiovascular disease',
 'no disease', ... ]
```

Comment: Please make you question reproducible by providing all necessary code and a sample of your data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254)

Comment: If you don't mind adding a column of colors to the dataframe, you can do it in the following way. `df=px.data.tips();df['color']=df['day'].map({'Sun':'red','Sat':'blue','Thur':'green','Fri':'yellow'});fig = px.histogram(df, x="day", color='color');fig.show()`

Comment: @r-beginners it still doesn't work correctly, it gives the same result I obtained above. I noticed that if I remove the `histnorm='probability density'` parameter it works correctly, showing the count, but this is not what I want to obtain, I would like to have the probability distribution, like in the first picture in the question