# Pandas: How to plot multiple lines against date using plotly as backend?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, plotly

I have the following dataframe:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

```
RangeIndex: 1642 entries, 0 to 1641
Data columns (total 13 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------            --------------  -----         
 0   Date              1642 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 1   Volgnr            1642 non-null   int64         
 2   account           1642 non-null   object        
 3   Rentedatum        1642 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 4   Bedrag            1642 non-null   float64       
 5   Balance           1642 non-null   float64       
 6   tegenrekening     906 non-null    object        
 7   Code              1642 non-null   object        
 8   Naam tegenpartij  1642 non-null   object        
 9   description       1642 non-null   object        
 10  category          1642 non-null   object        
 11  Grootboek         1578 non-null   object        
 12  Kleinboek         1578 non-null   object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(2), int64(1), object(8)
memory usage: 166.9+ KB
```

'account' has 5 different account numbers which like so: NL00ABCD0123456789

I want two different graphs but I'm already stuck with the first one
i.e. I want to see the balance over time for the 5 accounts

In line with other question on this forum I tried:

```
pd.options.plotting.backend="plotly"
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.groupby('account')['balance'].plot(legend=True)
```

But got the following error:

```
TypeError: line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'legend'
```

What is going wrong here?

For later:
If that is solved I want the X-axis to be weeks or months instead of the absolute date so some aggregation will be necessary

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the plotly library, but from the error I can surmise that the plot method does not have an attribute legend.  Check the docs to determine the proper attribute name for creating the legend.

Comment: can you provide a few sample rows of data?  struggling to understand the column names to generate something meaningful to provide an answer. additionally it's generally simpler to use the **plotly express** API rather than **pandas** wrapper layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

You're seeing this error because running `df.plot()` will trigger `px.line()` after defining `pd.options.plotting.backend="plotly"`.
And `px.line()` does not have a `legend` atribute. But you don't need it.
All you need is:

```
px.line(df, x = 'Date', y = 'Balance', color = 'Account')
```

And you'll get:

[image]

#### The details:

Setting `pd.options.plotting.backend="plotly"` will, as you surely may know, override the default plotting backend for `pandas` which is `matplotlib`. Still, when running `help(df.plot())` after that, the help info that pops up still seems to be info about `matplotlib`, which does in fact have a `legend` attribute.

But `px.line()` is what will be triggered by `df.plot()` after instantiating `pd.options.plotting.backend="plotly"`. And this is what triggers your error, since `px.line` does not have `legend` attribute. Dut don't worry about that, since things are about to get really simple for you, because `px.line()` will produce a grouped legend for you. You don't even need to group your data as long as you apply `df.plot()` correctly.

But before we come to that, we'll have to take a look at your provided dataset. Given the wording of your question, and the look of the 'data' what you've provided, my understanding is that you've got several non-unique accounts under `account` associated with different values for `balance` spread across multiple non-unique dates. Something like this:

```
          Date             Account  Balance
0   01.01.2022  NL00ABCD0123456789        1
1   01.01.2022  NL00ABCD0123456790        2
2   01.01.2022  NL00ABCD0123456791        2
3   01.01.2022  NL00ABCD0123456792        3
4   01.01.2022  NL00ABCD0123456793        4
5   02.01.2022  NL00ABCD0123456789        2
6   02.01.2022  NL00ABCD0123456790        3
7   02.01.2022  NL00ABCD0123456791        3
8   02.01.2022  NL00ABCD0123456792        4
9   02.01.2022  NL00ABCD0123456793        5
```

If that's the case, then all you need to do is run:

```
px.line(df, x = 'Date', y = 'Balance', color = 'Account')
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

pd.options.plotting.backend="plotly"
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '01.01.2022',
              1: '01.01.2022',
              2: '01.01.2022',
              3: '01.01.2022',
              4: '01.01.2022',
              5: '02.01.2022',
              6: '02.01.2022',
              7: '02.01.2022',
              8: '02.01.2022',
              9: '02.01.2022',
              10: '03.01.2022',
              11: '03.01.2022',
              12: '03.01.2022',
              13: '03.01.2022',
              14: '03.01.2022',
              15: '04.01.2022',
              16: '04.01.2022',
              17: '04.01.2022',
              18: '04.01.2022',
              19: '04.01.2022'},
             'Account': {0: 'NL00ABCD0123456789',
              1: 'NL00ABCD0123456790',
              2: 'NL00ABCD0123456791',
              3: 'NL00ABCD0123456792',
              4: 'NL00ABCD0123456793',
              5: 'NL00ABCD0123456789',
              6: 'NL00ABCD0123456790',
              7: 'NL00ABCD0123456791',
              8: 'NL00ABCD0123456792',
              9: 'NL00ABCD0123456793',
              10: 'NL00ABCD0123456789',
              11: 'NL00ABCD0123456790',
              12: 'NL00ABCD0123456791',
              13: 'NL00ABCD0123456792',
              14: 'NL00ABCD0123456793',
              15: 'NL00ABCD0123456789',
              16: 'NL00ABCD0123456790',
              17: 'NL00ABCD0123456791',
              18: 'NL00ABCD0123456792',
              19: 'NL00ABCD0123456793'},
             'Balance': {0: 1,
              1: 2,
              2: 2,
              3: 3,
              4: 4,
              5: 2,
              6: 3,
              7: 3,
              8: 4,
              9: 5,
              10: 3,
              11: 4,
              12: 4,
              13: 5,
              14: 6,
              15: 4,
              16: 5,
              17: 5,
              18: 6,
              19: 7}})

px.line(df, x = 'Date', y = 'Balance', color = 'Account')
```

Comment: I was out for a while and in the mean time several answers came in. Thanks all for taking the time to look at my problem. @vestland thanks very very much. You interpreted my missing data exactly right. (I don't know how you get it so quickly so much in stack overflow.)  I tried it and it worked. Top!

Comment: @matje59 Glad it worked for you! And thanks for the feedback! There are so many helpful, knowledgeable, talented and highly active users on the `plotly` tag these days so you *have* to be quick if you want to answer questions =)

Comment: @matje59 If you'd like how to easily enhance your future questions with a data sample, I would just like to suggest that you can follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254)

Comment: that's most helpful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided with a sample data, I have solution with an arbitrary time-series data.

```
{'Date': ['10/03/2004',
  '10/03/2004',
  '10/03/2004',
  '10/03/2004',
  '10/03/2004'],
 'Time': ['18.00.00', '19.00.00', '20.00.00', '21.00.00', '22.00.00'],
 'CO(GT)': ['2,6', '2', '2,2', '2,2', '1,6'],
 'PT08.S1(CO)': [1360.0, 1292.0, 1402.0, 1376.0, 1272.0],
 'NMHC(GT)': [150.0, 112.0, 88.0, 80.0, 51.0],
 'C6H6(GT)': ['11,9', '9,4', '9,0', '9,2', '6,5'],
 'PT08.S2(NMHC)': [1046.0, 955.0, 939.0, 948.0, 836.0],
 'NOx(GT)': [166.0, 103.0, 131.0, 172.0, 131.0],
 'PT08.S3(NOx)': [1056.0, 1174.0, 1140.0, 1092.0, 1205.0],
 'NO2(GT)': [113.0, 92.0, 114.0, 122.0, 116.0],
 'PT08.S4(NO2)': [1692.0, 1559.0, 1555.0, 1584.0, 1490.0],
 'PT08.S5(O3)': [1268.0, 972.0, 1074.0, 1203.0, 1110.0],
 'T': ['13,6', '13,3', '11,9', '11,0', '11,2'],
 'RH': ['48,9', '47,7', '54,0', '60,0', '59,6'],
 'AH': ['0,7578', '0,7255', '0,7502', '0,7867', '0,7888']
}
```

We need to convert date to a `datetime` object.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + " " + df['Time'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S")

# To plot with monthly aggregation you can use resample. 
df.set_index('Date').resample('1M').mean().plot()
```

[image]