# Conditional formatting data bars in plotly subplot tables

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Hi guys i have been struggling with this for days.
I have set up a subplot with 4 tables and the columns that are coloured, I actually want them to be data bars based off the min and max numbers in the column.

I have tried multiple different ways but cant get it to work. My current code is below.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.colors import n_colors


fig = make_subplots(
    rows=4, cols=1,
    subplot_titles=("Backs", "Edges", "Middles", "Halves, Hookers"),
    shared_xaxes=True,
    vertical_spacing=0.02,
    specs=[[{"type": "table"}],
           [{"type": "table"}],
           [{"type": "table"}],
           [{"type": "table"}]]
)


fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=list(Backs_cleaned.columns),
            fill_color='maroon',
            font=dict(size=10),
            font_color='white',
            line_color='lightgrey',
            align="center"
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=[Backs_cleaned.Round_x, Backs_cleaned.Name, Backs_cleaned.Minutes_x, Backs_cleaned.Game_x, Backs_cleaned.Con_x,
                   Backs_cleaned.Round_y,Backs_cleaned.Minutes_y, Backs_cleaned.Game_y, Backs_cleaned.Con_y, Backs_cleaned.Sum],
            font=dict(size=10),
            fill=dict(color=['white', 'white', 'lightgreen', 'salmon', 'lightgoldenrodyellow', 'white','lightgreen', 'salmon', 'lightgoldenrodyellow', 'white']),
            font_color='black',
            line_color='lightgrey',
            align = "center"),
            
    ),
    row=1, col=1
)


fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=list(Edges_cleaned.columns),
            fill_color='maroon',
            font=dict(size=10),
            font_color='white',
            line_color='lightgrey',
            align="center"
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=[Edges_cleaned.Round_x, Edges_cleaned.Name, Edges_cleaned.Minutes_x, Edges_cleaned.Game_x, Edges_cleaned.Con_x,
                   Edges_cleaned.Round_y,Edges_cleaned.Minutes_y, Edges_cleaned.Game_y, Edges_cleaned.Con_y, Edges_cleaned.Sum],
            fill=dict(color=['white', 'white', 'lightgreen', 'salmon', 'lightgoldenrodyellow', 'white','lightgreen', 'salmon', 'lightgoldenrodyellow', 'white']),
            font=dict(size=10),
            font_color='black',
            line_color='lightgrey',
            align = "center")
    ),
    row=2, col=1
)



fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=list(Middles_cleaned.columns),
            fill_color='maroon',
            font=dict(size=10),
            font_color='white',
            line_color='lightgrey',
            align="center"
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=[Middles_cleaned.Round_x, Middles_cleaned.Name, Middles_cleaned.Minutes_x, Middles_cleaned.Game_x, Middles_cleaned.Con_x,
                   Middles_cleaned.Round_y,Middles_cleaned.Minutes_y, Middles_cleaned.Game_y, Middles_cleaned.Con_y, Middles_cleaned.Sum],
            fill=dict(color=['white', 'white', 'lightgreen', 'salmon', 'lightgoldenrodyellow', 'white','lightgreen', 'salmon', 'lightgoldenrodyellow', 'white']),
            font=dict(size=10),
            font_color='black',
            line_color='lightgrey',
            align = "center")
    ),
    row=3, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=list(HH_cleaned.columns),
            fill_color='maroon',
            font=dict(size=10),
            font_color='white',
            line_color='lightgrey',
            align="center"
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=[HH_cleaned.Round_x, HH_cleaned.Name, HH_cleaned.Minutes_x, HH_cleaned.Game_x, HH_cleaned.Con_x,
                   HH_cleaned.Round_y,HH_cleaned.Minutes_y, HH_cleaned.Game_y, HH_cleaned.Con_y, HH_cleaned.Sum],
            fill=dict(color=['white', 'white', 'lightgreen', 'salmon', 'lightgoldenrodyellow', 'white','lightgreen', 'salmon', 'lightgoldenrodyellow', 'white']),
            font=dict(size=10),
            font_color='black',
            line_color='lightgrey',
            align = "center")
    ),
    row=4, col=1
)

fig.update_layout(
    height=1600,

    showlegend=False,
    title_text="Longitudinal Conditioning Minutes",
)


fig.show()
```

And here is a copy of the figure output where I want to change the coloured columns to data bars using the same colours. Thanks for your help in advance!
[image: Output]

[image]

```
pd.DataFrame({'Round_x': {0: 0.1,
  1: 0.1,
  2: 0.1,
  3: 0.1,
  4: 0.1,
  5: 0.1,
  6: 0.1,
  7: 0.1,
  8: 0.1,
  9: 0.1,
  10: 0.1,
  11: ''},
 'Name': {0: 'Jesse Arthars',
  1: 'Corey Oates',
  2: 'Herbie Farnworth',
  3: 'Tristan Sailor',
  4: 'Selwyn Cobbo',
  5: 'Ethan Quai-Ward',
  6: 'Jordan Pereira',
  7: 'Kotoni Staggs',
  8: 'Delouise Hoeter',
  9: 'Deine Mariner',
  10: 'Reece Walsh',
  11: 'Average'},
 'Minutes_x': {0: 31.0,
  1: 30.0,
  2: 37.0,
  3: 33.0,
  4: 30.0,
  5: 26.0,
  6: 37.0,
  7: 26.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 15.0,
  10: 11.0,
  11: 25.0},
 'Game_x': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 27,
  4: 0,
  5: 27,
  6: 0,
  7: 0,
  8: 40,
  9: 0,
  10: 0,
  11: ''},
 'Con_x': {0: 6,
  1: 6,
  2: 6,
  3: 0,
  4: 6,
  5: 0,
  6: 12,
  7: 6,
  8: 17,
  9: 15,
  10: 16,
  11: ''},
 'Round_y': {0: 1.0,
  1: 1.0,
  2: 1.0,
  3: 1.0,
  4: 1.0,
  5: 1.0,
  6: 1.0,
  7: 1.0,
  8: 1.0,
  9: 1.0,
  10: 1.0,
  11: ''},
 'Minutes_y': {0: 24.0,
  1: 23.0,
  2: 14.0,
  3: 18.0,
  4: 13.0,
  5: 16.0,
  6: 9.0,
  7: 18.0,
  8: 7.0,
  9: 18.0,
  10: 24.0,
  11: 17.0},
 'Game_y': {0: 63.0,
  1: 63.0,
  2: 63.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 63.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 39.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: ''},
 'Con_y': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 35.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 29.0,
  6: 35.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 20.0,
  9: 31.0,
  10: 19.0,
  11: ''},
 'Sum': {0: 124.0,
  1: 122.0,
  2: 120.0,
  3: 113.0,
  4: 112.0,
  5: 98.0,
  6: 93.0,
  7: 89.0,
  8: 84.0,
  9: 79.0,
  10: 70.0,
  11: 100.0}})
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the graph you want. Do you have a desired output graph? And can you provide some sample data on which we can run your code?

Comment: So the output is currently as I want it however instead of the plain column background colours I would like data bars like so

Comment: You ask for the equivalent functionality in plotly to the examples in the pandas [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Bar-charts). I have not seen this functionality to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to unleash [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/), there are a few examples in the docs on [Diverging Data Bars](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/conditional-formatting#diverging-data-bars) that should fit your needs perfectly:

Apply the code in the snippet below to produce the following plot based on your dataset:

#### Plot

[image]

Just add or remove column references in this part in the `data_bars()` function to add or remove formatted columns:

```
style_data_conditional=(
    data_bars(df, 'Minutes_x') +
    data_bars(df, 'Minutes_y')
)
```

If you'd like diverging colors, use `data_bars_diverging()` instead.

#### Complete code

```
# %%
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd

df_gapminder = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv')
df = df_gapminder[:500]


df = pd.DataFrame({'Round_x': {0: 0.1,
                               1: 0.1,
                               2: 0.1,
                               3: 0.1,
                               4: 0.1,
                               5: 0.1,
                               6: 0.1,
                               7: 0.1,
                               8: 0.1,
                               9: 0.1,
                               10: 0.1,
                               11: ''},
                   'Name': {0: 'Jesse Arthars',
                            1: 'Corey Oates',
                            2: 'Herbie Farnworth',
                            3: 'Tristan Sailor',
                            4: 'Selwyn Cobbo',
                            5: 'Ethan Quai-Ward',
                            6: 'Jordan Pereira',
                            7: 'Kotoni Staggs',
                            8: 'Delouise Hoeter',
                            9: 'Deine Mariner',
                            10: 'Reece Walsh',
                            11: 'Average'},
                   'Minutes_x': {0: 31.0,
                                 1: 30.0,
                                 2: 37.0,
                                 3: 33.0,
                                 4: 30.0,
                                 5: 26.0,
                                 6: 37.0,
                                 7: 26.0,
                                 8: 0.0,
                                 9: 15.0,
                                 10: 11.0,
                                 11: 25.0},
                   'Game_x': {0: 0,
                              1: 0,
                              2: 0,
                              3: 27,
                              4: 0,
                              5: 27,
                              6: 0,
                              7: 0,
                              8: 40,
                              9: 0,
                              10: 0,
                              11: ''},
                   'Con_x': {0: 6,
                             1: 6,
                             2: 6,
                             3: 0,
                             4: 6,
                             5: 0,
                             6: 12,
                             7: 6,
                             8: 17,
                             9: 15,
                             10: 16,
                             11: ''},
                   'Round_y': {0: 1.0,
                               1: 1.0,
                               2: 1.0,
                               3: 1.0,
                               4: 1.0,
                               5: 1.0,
                               6: 1.0,
                               7: 1.0,
                               8: 1.0,
                               9: 1.0,
                               10: 1.0,
                               11: ''},
                   'Minutes_y': {0: 24.0,
                                 1: 23.0,
                                 2: 14.0,
                                 3: 18.0,
                                 4: 13.0,
                                 5: 16.0,
                                 6: 9.0,
                                 7: 18.0,
                                 8: 7.0,
                                 9: 18.0,
                                 10: 24.0,
                                 11: 17.0},
                   'Game_y': {0: 63.0,
                              1: 63.0,
                              2: 63.0,
                              3: 0.0,
                              4: 63.0,
                              5: 0.0,
                              6: 0.0,
                              7: 39.0,
                              8: 0.0,
                              9: 0.0,
                              10: 0.0,
                              11: ''},
                   'Con_y': {0: 0.0,
                             1: 0.0,
                             2: 0.0,
                             3: 35.0,
                             4: 0.0,
                             5: 29.0,
                             6: 35.0,
                             7: 0.0,
                             8: 20.0,
                             9: 31.0,
                             10: 19.0,
                             11: ''},
                   'Sum': {0: 124.0,
                           1: 122.0,
                           2: 120.0,
                           3: 113.0,
                           4: 112.0,
                           5: 98.0,
                           6: 93.0,
                           7: 89.0,
                           8: 84.0,
                           9: 79.0,
                           10: 70.0,
                           11: 100.0}})
# %%
app = Dash(__name__)


def data_bars(df, column):
    n_bins = 100
    bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins + 1)]
    ranges = [
        ((df[column].max() - df[column].min()) * i) + df[column].min()
        for i in bounds
    ]
    styles = []
    for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
        min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
        max_bound = ranges[i]
        max_bound_percentage = bounds[i] * 100
        styles.append({
            'if': {
                'filter_query': (
                    '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                    (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (
                        i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                'column_id': column
            },
            'background': (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    #0074D9 0%,
                    #0074D9 {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(max_bound_percentage=max_bound_percentage)
            ),
            'paddingBottom': 2,
            'paddingTop': 2
        })

    return styles


def data_bars(df, column):
    n_bins = 100
    bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins + 1)]
    ranges = [
        ((df[column].max() - df[column].min()) * i) + df[column].min()
        for i in bounds
    ]
    styles = []
    for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
        min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
        max_bound = ranges[i]
        max_bound_percentage = bounds[i] * 100
        styles.append({
            'if': {
                'filter_query': (
                    '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                    (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (
                        i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                'column_id': column
            },
            'background': (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    #0074D9 0%,
                    #0074D9 {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(max_bound_percentage=max_bound_percentage)
            ),
            'paddingBottom': 2,
            'paddingTop': 2
        })

    return styles


def data_bars_diverging(df, column, color_above='#3D9970', color_below='#FF4136'):
    n_bins = 100
    bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins + 1)]
    col_max = df[column].max()
    col_min = df[column].min()
    ranges = [
        ((col_max - col_min) * i) + col_min
        for i in bounds
    ]
    midpoint = (col_max + col_min) / 2.

    styles = []
    for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
        min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
        max_bound = ranges[i]
        min_bound_percentage = bounds[i - 1] * 100
        max_bound_percentage = bounds[i] * 100

        style = {
            'if': {
                'filter_query': (
                    '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                    (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (
                        i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                'column_id': column
            },
            'paddingBottom': 2,
            'paddingTop': 2
        }
        if max_bound > midpoint:
            background = (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    white 0%,
                    white 50%,
                    {color_above} 50%,
                    {color_above} {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white {max_bound_percentage}%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(
                    max_bound_percentage=max_bound_percentage,
                    color_above=color_above
                )
            )
        else:
            background = (
                """
                    linear-gradient(90deg,
                    white 0%,
                    white {min_bound_percentage}%,
                    {color_below} {min_bound_percentage}%,
                    {color_below} 50%,
                    white 50%,
                    white 100%)
                """.format(
                    min_bound_percentage=min_bound_percentage,
                    color_below=color_below
                )
            )
        style['background'] = background
        styles.append(style)

    return styles


app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    sort_action='native',
    columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns],
    style_data_conditional=(
        data_bars(df, 'Minutes_x') +
        data_bars(df, 'Minutes_y')
    ),
    style_cell={
        'width': '100px',
        'minWidth': '100px',
        'maxWidth': '100px',
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
    },
    page_size=20
)


app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    sort_action='native',
    columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns],
    style_data_conditional=(
        data_bars(df, 'Minutes_x') +
        data_bars(df, 'Minutes_y')
    ),
    style_cell={
        'width': '100px',
        'minWidth': '100px',
        'maxWidth': '100px',
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
    },
    page_size=20
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: Hopefully this works. https://github.com/jakejennings1/DataDump.git

Comment: Using that data I just split it into the seperate positional groups and concat round 1 to round 0.1

Comment: @Jake That link does not work on my end. You can more easily share a chunk of your data like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254).

Comment: I have now added a sample of the Backs df above

Comment: Thanks so much this is excellent! Only thing I now need to do is make it a subplot with multiple positional groups like my first example. I am struggling to adapt my non dash sublot code to incorporate the dash components. How would I adapt the code you just sent to incorporate the same table twice?

Comment: @Jake With Dash you don't have to worry about the boundaries of subplots. You can make almost whatever you want. Dash is for apps that contain Plotly objects (but not limited to that), but you can embed apps in JupyterLab with JupyterDash as well.